# Как проверить переменную в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Как проверить что бы в переменной было только цифры, но не было другого шлака, к примеру `http://example.com/?a=1&b=3` А вот если вот такой шлак `http://example.com/?a=1&b=3...l`, то отправлять на `http://example.com/?a=1`

Это правило сработает если там все цифры:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=1&b=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?a=1&b=%1 [R=301,L]
```

А это если там цифр вообще нет:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=1&b=(^\d+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?a=1&b=%1 [R=301,L]
```

UPD. линки могут быть разными, но проверить надо только `b=(\d)`:

```
http://example.com/?a=1
http://example.com/?a=1&b=3
http://example.com/?a=1&b=3&c=4
```

Answer (score 1):

Для случая если параметр `a=1`, а параметр `b` следует сразу за параметром `a` вот `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=1&b=.*[^\d]
RewriteRule .* /?a=1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: это мне кажется, что оно сработает на все вподряд?

Comment: Так проверьте его.

Comment: @yarnik, хотя возможно стоит `^a=1&b=.*[^\d]` заменить на `^a=1&b=(.*[^\d].*)?$`, чтобы пустой параметр `b` тоже удалялся.

Comment: вот `^a=1&b=.*[^\d]` - работает вроде, не знал что так можно, а `^a=1&b=(.*[^\d].*)?` - редиректит даже с `?a=1&b=3`

Comment: @yarnik, у меня оба правила с `?a=1&b=3` ни куда не редиректят. Прочитайте еще раз мой комментарий, вы забыли про указатель на конец строки `$`!

Comment: мне не надо конец строки ;)

Comment: нет, все равно редиректит если за ним ним есть другие парраметры: `?a=1&b=3` - все ок, `?a=1&b=3&c=2` - редирект

Comment: @yarnik, это уже другой вопрос. Формируйте сразу свои вопросы полно, чтобы по 10 раз на дню не менялись условия задачи.

Comment: согласен, но думал что это сильно повлияет